# Entity Framework: check existence of record before inserting a new one

Tags: entity-framework, insert

In my web app a user can assign muliple tags to products (like the tagging here on stackoverflow). 
There are three tables: products, tags and products_tags to implement a many to many relationship.

My question is, how would you implement this with the Entity Framework (LINQ to SQL):
"Insert only a new tag in the tags table  if it doesnt already exist there". 
So before the insert i have to check first if a tag exists, whats the best way to accomplish this (best performance) ??

thanks for answers

Comment: Just a note: Entity Framework and LINQ to SQL are two different ORM frameworks, I gather you're trying to use EF not L2S, right?

Comment: Oh yes you are right... i meant "LINQ to Entities"

Answer (score 0):

Simple: The Tag should then be the user assigned key/PK of the entity/table.

If you have troubles synchronizing this with the database, I am sure there's something like (N)Hibernate's merge Method in EntityFramework.

Comment: The Tags table consists of TagID (PK) and TagName... 
thanks for the answer but it doesnt really help me